# Combining view layer and automatic route generation

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1, fosrestbundle

I am having problems including `FOSRestBundle` in my `Symfony 2.1` project.

When I use automatic route generation ( [documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/5-automatic-route-generation_single-restful-controller.md) ) and want to use the `view layer` ( [documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/2-the-view-layer.md) ).

I receive an exception: **No route found for "GET /users"**.

My config.yml:

```
fos_rest:
  routing_loader:
    default_format: json
```

My routing.yml:

```
users:
  type:     rest
  resource: Api\UserBundle\Controller\UsersController
```

My UsersController class:

```
namespace Api\UserBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;

class UsersController extends FOSRestController
{ 
  public function getUsersAction() { die('get'); }
  public function postUsersAction() { die('post'); }
}
```

When I remove `extends FOSRestController` everything works - but I lose the view layer functionality. Anyone who can steer me in the right direction to solving this problem?

Comment: please try `router:debug` in the console first

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you manage to solve it by now... But I had the very same problem and it seems to come from the fact that FOSRestController implements ClassResourceInterface (FOSRestBundle will determine the resource based on the Controller name).

All I had to do to make it work was omitting the resource name from the methods.
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/5-automatic-route-generation_single-restful-controller.md

/ jonas